# jQuery UI Datepicker position bottom or top but not both

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using the Datepicker plugin and customizing it to my needs. I was able to do mostly everything I needed in CSS but there's one thing that is bothering me. When the calendar opens depending on where you are on your screen it will appear on top or under the input. How can I have control over this behavior? I'm trying to adapt it to a responsive layout so sometimes I want it on top and other times I want it under but not both.

Comment: You might want to look at this related question and answer:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658009/set-jquery-datepicker-position-to-top-of-text-field/25844251#25844251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datepicker calls `$.datepicker._checkOffset` to calculate the position.

I would grab the original function (from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js)) and redefine it according to my needs.