# Set jquery datepicker position to top of text field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Jquery datepicker shows at under the test field. Some time it will top of text field. But I want show the datepicker always in top of the test field. How to do it?

Answer (score 11):

The following code will position the calendar always on top of input field.

```
$('.txtDate').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
       var txtBoxOffset = $(this).offset();
       var top = txtBoxOffset.top;
       var left = txtBoxOffset.left;
       var textBoxWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
       console.log('top: ' + top + 'left: ' + left);
               setTimeout(function () {
                   instance.dpDiv.css({
                       top: top-190, //you can adjust this value accordingly
                       left: left + textBoxWidth//show at the end of textBox
               });
           }, 0);

   }});
```

Comment: For the Calendar to show up on top left corner of textbox, follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezkc4p12/)

Comment: every month can have different number of rows thus the calendar height is really variable - maybe the reason why the original implementation always places calendar below text field

Answer (score 1):

Use at your own risk...

```
.ui-datepicker {
    position: relative !important;
    top: -290px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mXnjS/1/

You may need to update top px as it depends on your base font size.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                    marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 'px'
            });
          }
      });
```

If you have two or more datepickers in one page, this code changes the position of all of them. If you need to change each one separately, you should use this code...

```
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
       setTimeout(function () {
           inst.dpDiv.css({
            top: 100,
                left: 200
        });
      }, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this :


$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                    marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 'px'
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Make-jQuery-datepicker-to-popup-in-different-positions-995.php. It will show on the right of the textbox: http://jsfiddle.net/4mGkn/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#StartDateIssued,#EndDateIssued,#StartDateFulFill,#EndDateFulFill').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        var offset = $(input).offset();
        var height = $(input).height();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            inst.dpDiv.css({ top: (offset.top + height - 20) + 'px', marginLeft: ( input.offsetWidth) + 'px' })
        })},
    changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, constrainInput: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#StartDateIssued').valid();
        $('#StartDateIssued').val(dateText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to workaround this using this hack, based on the original jQuery UI's "_checkOffset" function:

```
function datepickerInitDirectionReverse() {
    // Store original method to be able to call it inside our overriding method.
    $.datepicker._checkOffset_original = $.datepicker._checkOffset;
    $.datepicker._checkOffset = function(inst, offset, isFixed) {
        var dpHeight = inst.dpDiv.outerHeight(),
            inputHeight = inst.input ? inst.input.outerHeight() : 0,
            viewTop = isFixed ? 0 : $(document).scrollTop();
        offset = $.datepicker._checkOffset_original(inst, offset, isFixed);
        // Try to reposition the datepicker on top of it,
        // only if the option flag is set by the user
        // and only if this has not already happened.
        offset.top -= Math.min(
            offset.top,
            (
                this._get(inst, "directionReverse")
                &&
                (offset.top > inst.input.offset().top)
                &&
                (offset.top - viewTop > dpHeight)
            ) ? Math.abs(dpHeight + inputHeight) : 0
        );
        return offset;
    }
}
```

Now you could configure your positioning preference as follows on a per element base:

```
// Prefer datepicker to appear on top of input element (if room).
$(element).datepicker({
    directionReverse: true
});

// Prefer datepicker to appear on bottom of input element (if room).
// This is the unchanged default behaviour.
$(element).datepicker({
    directionReverse: false
});
```

Beware that the above might break in future versions of jQuery UI, if the developers decide to change the interfaces. Also please let me know if there be would any side effects.

Answer (score -3):

jquery datepicker is designed like it doesn't need any changes...only it can be moved left or right by making changes in the css of the datepicker... check your html version because datepicker doesn't support html version 5.. html version 4 is supported

Comment: We can do lot of configuration with Jquery Ui.