# jQuery timepicker: popup upwards and content height

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using a jquery timepicker in a small web page (not resizable)

My timepicker is at the bottom and I need the control popup to be displayed upwards (if possible) and with a small height (for the popup, not for the input control)

I found nothing about upwards (my preference)

About popup height, if I set:

```
   .ui-timepicker {
       height: 50px;
   }
```

my popup element has small height but not its content

Any help about upwards or content height?

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: inspect the popup and change the CSS to your desired result and then add it manually into your page?

Comment: Can you put some code here?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658009/set-jquery-datepicker-position-to-top-of-text-field and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662220/how-to-change-the-pop-up-position-of-the-jquery-datepicker-control and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131465/how-to-change-jquery-ui-datepicker-position/15131574